# Ipyvuetify and matplotlib.pyplot display order

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vuetify.js, ipywidgets

I was trying to display a set of ipyvuetify select widgets which trigger a function and plot a figure. Although I was able to make it work as I expected, I can't seem to place the pyplot figure below the select widgets.

```py
city_select=v.Select(
    prepend_icon='mdi-home-city',
    style_='width: 300px',
    v_model='e7',
    items=['Bo Town','Kenema City'],
    label='City Name',
    chips=True    
    )
hospital_select=v.Select(
    prepend_icon='mdi-hospital-box',
    style_='width: 300px',
    items=['Lion Heart Hospital','Kindoya Hospital','Port Loko Government Hospital','Holy Spirit Catholic Hosp'],
    label='Hospital Name (1)',
    multiple=True,
    chips=True
    ) 
hospital_EEZ_select=v.Select(
    prepend_icon='mdi-hospital-box',
    style_='width: 300px',
    items=['Lion Heart Hospital','Kindoya Hospital','Port Loko Government Hospital','Holy Spirit Catholic Hosp'],
    label='Hospital Name (2)',
    multiple=True,
    chips=True
    )

select_show=v.Html(tag='div', class_='d-flex flex-row', children=[
    v.Html(tag='div', class_='d-flex flex-column', children=[
        #v.Html(tag='h3', children=['Country Map']),
        v.Chip(class_='ma-2',
              color='success',
              outlined=True,
              children=['Country Map']),
        city_select,
    ]),
    v.Html(tag='div', class_='d-flex flex-column', children=[
        v.Chip(class_='ma-2',
              color='deep-purple accent-4',
              outlined=True,
              children=['City Map']),
        hospital_select
    ]),
    v.Html(tag='div', class_='d-flex flex-column', children=[
        v.Chip(class_='ma-2',
              color='indigo darken-3',
              outlined=True,
              children=['Maritime']),
        hospital_EEZ_select
    ]),
    ])
fig,ax=pp.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
v.Container(children=[select_show])
```

I considered putting the pyplot figure in an output widget, and then put this widget in select_show. However, I couldn't find any widgets in ipyvuetify which is equivalent to the output widget in ipywidgets.

Is there any simpler solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone landing here in search for an answer:

in a ipywidget you can either string, ro list of DOMWidgets in the children trait of your widgets (which means other widgets).

To display a chart, 2 solutions:

- use a `bqplot` (which is an interactive DOMWidget)
- wrap your pyplot in the Output widget of `ipywidgets`

In your case it would be something like:

```py
from ipywidgets import Output
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

city_select=v.Select() # whatever arguments    
hospital_select=v.Select() # whatever arguments 
hospital_EEZ_select=v.Select() # whatever arguments

plot = Output()
with plot as out:
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
    plt.show()

app = v.Layout(
    row = True,
    children = [city_select, hospital_select, hospital_EEZ_select, plot]
)

display(app)
```

keep in mind that the pyplot will not actualize itself when you change your parameters. For this purpose prefer to use a `bqplot` as shown in this [tutorial](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila-vuetify/blob/master/bqplot_vuetify_example.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting the figure in the output widget, and then used the GirdspecLayout from ipywidgets to display everything.